# Google Drive API Check if File is Shared With Me

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am creating an android app which uses Google Sheets API V4 and Google Drive API V2 to edit a Google Spreadsheet. But I am having an issue. I need to be able to check if the spreadsheet is shared with the user who is logged into the device and if they can edit it or if they are an owner. I have tried
`Boolean canEdit = driveService.files().get(fileId).execute().getEditable();`
and
`Boolean canEdit = driveService.files()
.get(fileId).execute().getCapabilities().getCanEdit();`
but both of those seem to only work if the user owns the file. I think that that is because the command `files().get(id)` can only get the files in the users drive; not any files that are shared with the user. I have also tried
`String role = driveService.permissions().get(fileId, driveService 
.about().get().execute().getPermissionId()).execute().getRole();`
but this seems to also only look for files in the users Drive. All of these commands throw 404 Not Found if the user is not an owner.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [Handling API Errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#404_file_not_found_fileid), `404: File not found` could be that the user does not have read access to a file.

And, AFAIK, requests which needs access to user data requires s particular scope of access. However, as noted in [Authorizing Android Apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api), the Google Drive Android API currently only supports `drive.file` and `drive.appfolder` authorization scopes.

With this, you may want to authorize your requests using the [Google APIs Java Client](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_with_the_google_apis_java_client) and instead use the Google Drive web service to [search for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) that are shared with you.